# Запрос базы данных Django: как получить объект по id?

Tags: django

Django автоматически создает поле id в качестве первичного ключа.

Теперь мне нужно получить объект по этому id.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, verbose_name='id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='name')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id = # указываете id

person = Person.objects.get(pk=id)

Comment: значение pk ожидал число, а вы передали id